# Как записать строку в файл по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: java, javafx

есть **asd.java**

```
 import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;



    public class Asd extends Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {launch(args);}
        Button button;
        String a="something";
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            Pane pane =new Pane();
            button =new Button("button");
            pane.getChildren().add(button);
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane,400,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
    }
```

и **qw.java**

```
public class qw {
}
```

после нажатия добавить `String a` в **qw.java**
...

и в **qw.java** должен быть вот так`something`

[image: qw][image: resuly]

Comment: вы хотите во время работы программы создать код, откомпилировать его и запустить? или вы хотите управлять IDE из программы на java? или что-то другое?

Comment: исправил!! мне очень нужна Ваша помощь !! пожалуйста помогите мне

Comment: вы хотите добавить текст в файл после нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: да!! например у меня есть `String a ="something";` после нажатие...я хочу видеть в **asd.java**  только `something`

Comment: исправьте вопрос. уберите бесполезные скриншоты.

Comment: убрал скриншоты и добавиль коды

Comment: проверьте заголовок вопроса - я его исправил. это то, что вы спрашиваете? или я неправильно понял?